# Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem $(g-f)$ is finite, is well defined?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

[image]

In the proof at (1) appears $\int_E(g-f)$. My question is:
How we can be sure $g-f$ is well defined (is not $\infty-\infty$)
 Since Lebesgue integrability do not involve bounded. How g-f is well defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both $f$ and $g$ are Lebesgue-integrable. Therefore, the set where $f$ can be $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ is a set of measure 0. The same goes for $g$.

You are right, there can be points where $g-f$ is really not defined, but because of the argument above this can only happen on a set with measure 0 which can be neglected when dealing with Lebesgue-integration.

Comment: we know $f_n ->f$ almost everywhere but we don't know  f and g are finite almost everywhere but: because g is L.integrabile then g must be finite almost everywhere? the same for f.

Comment: Yes, $g$ is Lebesgue-integrable and therefore it has to be finite almost everywhere (otherwise the integral would not converge). $f$ is also Lebesgue-integrable as it is dominated by $g$ and so $f$ is also finite almost everywhere.

Comment: how we can prove  $\int_X g<\infty $ involve g is finite almost ev.wh.?

Comment: $\int_Xg < \infty$ also implies that $\int_X |g| < \infty$. If now $g$ is infinite on a set with measure greater than $0$, $\int_X |g| = \infty$ and thus a contradiction.

Comment: ouuu yes thank you